# Why facebook's image sprite not dense

Tags: facebook, image, css-sprites

I was looking at some image sprites of facebook and found this https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yA/r/Xt1SK8GpuTC.png

I am wondering why exactly there is so much of white space in this image sprite, when they could have easily compressed the icons on a much smaller image

Answer (score 0):

Because empty space takes up no memory in an image, there is no reason not to leave some space for future use.  What I would like to know, is why their [current sprite](https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yk/r/v5kmQv-y2dW.png) has their logo in it two times, and why, when you view the homepage, did they allow remnants to be shown of the one below it, to varying degrees, depending on what browser is being used.